# Is there any way to get the "filter name" inside the common custom filter function defined against it

Tags: jinja2

I have written generic custom filters.

```
def common_custom_filter_func(**args, **kwargs):
     print(filter name)
```

And there are many filters with different names mapped to the same function

```
{
"filter1": common_custom_filter_func,
"filter2": common_custom_filter_func,
}
```

Is there any way I can get my filter name inside the filter function when its called? For example, I need to catch the name filter1 inside common_custom_filter_func when the below template is called. And respectively for filter2

```
{{ data | filter1 }} ----> prints filter1
{{ data | filter2 }} ----> prints filter2
```

I tried pass_context but it does not have any attribute that has the caller filter name.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use case? Why not just define multiple functions, and them have them call out to `common_custom_filter_func`?

Comment: Yeah could have done that but its functioning is dynamic. 
filter1 and filter2 in my case are rest api action and which exact api they map to  is fetched from database.  If there is new api a new action say filter3 can be created in db runtime and used by clients without the need of writing a new filter function in file statically.I look to utilise same common filter function and if get the actual filter name then I can fetch the right api against it from db and get the data.  For simplicity we do not want client to pass any specific parameter in template expression for this identification.

Comment: @larsks let me know if its not clear , i will try to explain. Additionally we want clients to simply pass  {{ data | filter1 }} . Based on this filter name I want to call the right api. I can not do this one to one as the apis are dynamic and created runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the name by which a filter function was called from within the function by default.

You could pass in the name as a parameter, something like:

```
import jinja2

from functools import partial


def common_custom_filter_func(filter_name, value):
    return f"{filter_name}: {value}"


def main():
    env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader("templates"))
    env.filters |= {
        "filter1": partial(common_custom_filter_func, "filter1"),
        "filter2": partial(common_custom_filter_func, "filter2"),
        "filter3": partial(common_custom_filter_func, "filter3"),
    }
    t = env.get_template("example.j2.txt")
    print(t.render())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Assuming that `example.j2.txt` looks like this:

```
This is a test.

Using filter1: {{ "some data" | filter1 }}

Using filter2: {{ "more data" | filter2 }}
```

This will produce:

```
This is a test.

Using filter1: filter1: some data

Using filter2: filter2: more data
```